# rethinkdb - hasFields to find all documents with multiple multiple missing conditions

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I found an answer for finding all documents in a table with missing fields in this SO thread  [RethinkDB - Find documents with missing field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724041/rethinkdb-find-documents-with-missing-field), however I want to filter according to a missing field AND a certain value in a different field.

I want to return all documents that are missing field `email` and whose  `isCurrent:` value is `1`. So, I want to return all current clients who are missing the email field, so that I can add the field.
The documentation on rethink's site does not cover this case.

Here's my best attempt:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter(function (row) {
  return row.hasFields({email: true }).not(),
/*no idea how to add another criteria here (such as .filter({isCurrent:1})*/

  }).filter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can do it in one `filter`. And, also, it will be faster than your current solution:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter(function (row) {
    return row.hasFields({email: true }).not()
      .and(row.hasFields({isCurrent: true }))
      .and(row("isCurrent").eq(1));
})
```

or:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter(function (row) {
    return row.hasFields({email: true }).not()
      .and(row("isCurrent").default(0).eq(1));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized I can chain multiple `.filter` commands. 
Here's what worked for me:

```
r.db('client').table('basic_info').filter(function (row) {
    return row.hasFields({email: true }).not()
}).filter({isCurrent: 1}).;
```

My next quest: put all of these into an array and then feed the email addresses in batch